Intuition behind Welch's ANOVA
I run some simulations and naturally Welch's ANOVA for unequal variances is pretty good compared to classic ANOVA and it seems it has no downsides. However, I still lack understanding as to why it works as well as it does. To be precise, why it is that when we use weights that are inverse of the variance we manage to keep the false positive and false negative rates at nominal values and why it's the case that Sum Squares Model that we calculate using those weights follows a Chi2 distribution. How does this property arise?
I am not a mathematical person but I try to build intuition behind every concept.
